# Cannot authenticate into AWS Opensearch in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am using Java, Spring, Spring boot and AWS Sdk to authenticate/login into my OpenSearch Cluster on AWS.
Here is the article I'm following in the AWS Docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/request-signing.html#request-signing-java

I have my AWS credentials configured globally and I am basically trying to sign my requests with my credentials (accessKeyId, secretAccessKey), however, It's not recognizing that my credentials are configured.

**Here is my configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
public class PostsOpenSearchRestClientConfiguration {
    private String opensearchEndpoint = "https://search-posts-a1b2c3d4e5f6g7.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com";
    private int opensearchPort = 9200;
    private String scheme = "https";
    private String region = "us-east-1";
    private String myServiceName = "es";
    private String opensearchClusterUsername = "myUser";
    private String opensearchClusterPassword = "myPass";

    
    private String accessKeyId = "abcdefxxxxx";
    private String secretAccessKey = "123xxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Bean
    public OpenSearchClient myOpensearchClient(){
        final BasicAWSCredentials myCredentialsProvider = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();
        OpenSearchTransport transport = new AwsSdk2Transport(httpClient, opensearchEndpoint, Region.US_EAST_1, AwsSdk2TransportOptions.builder().build());
        return new OpenSearchClient(transport);
    }
}
```

**Here is the error I'm getting:**

> software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException:
> **Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain AwsCredentialsProviderChain**(credentialsProviders=[SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider(),
> EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(), ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default),
> ContainerCredentialsProvider(), InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider()]) : [SystemPropertyCredentialsProvider():
> **Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId)., EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(): Unable to load credentials from system settings. Access key must be specified either via environment variable (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) or system property (aws.accessKeyId).**, WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider(): Either the environment variable AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE
> or the javaproperty aws.webIdentityTokenFile must be set., ProfileCredentialsProvider(profileName=default): Expected an '=' sign defining a property on line 4, ContainerCredentialsProvider(): Cannot fetch credentials from container - neither AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI or AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI environment variables are set., InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(): Failed to
> load credentials from IMDS.]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You’re not using your `myCredentialsProvider` variable. But if you’re running on an EC2 instance, the recommended way is to give the instance role the required permissions and let the AWS SDK use it without having to create access keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot authenticate into my Opensearch cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74346380/cannot-authenticate-into-my-opensearch-cluster)

Comment: Hi @Strelok I am using the AWS Opensearch service https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/opensearch/

Comment: I am also facing the same issue any pointers to issue is of great help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```java
    @Bean
    public OpenSearchClient myOpensearchClient(){
        final BasicAwsCredentials credentials = new BasicAwsCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        final AwsCredentialsProvider provider = StaticCredentialsProvider
            .create(credentials);

        SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();
        OpenSearchTransport transport = new AwsSdk2Transport(
            httpClient, 
            opensearchEndpoint, 
            Region.<your_region>, 
            AwsSdk2TransportOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(provider)
                .build());
        return new OpenSearchClient(transport);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).